# Method of launching code on multiple Pi simultaneously over WiFi

Tags: wifi, communication

I have several Pi Zero W's each with a Pimoroni 'Phat' attached. I have three different types of these 'Phats'. I would like to be able to launch one of three programs that control these, so the same program runs on ALL the Pi's, launching simultaneously so as to keep visual effects in sync.

What would be the best method to do this? Either from one of the Pi's, or from a Mac?

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to use [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux):

- Run `tmux` locally with split window side by side
- Run `ssh` to login each raspi in each panes
- Run `tmux` command with `:set synchronize-panes`
- Run whatever command you like in sync-mode